# Regexp for TextField validator in QML

Tags: javascript, regex, qt, qml

I need my text field accepts only numbers (1-3 digits) separated by comma.

Examples:

**Accepted:**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
12,47,234,67
```

**Not accepted:**

```
a,2,6,3
4567,3,8
```

I tried:

- (\d{1,3}\,{0,1})
- (\d+),{0,1}
- (\d)+,((\d)+,)*(\d)+

  But from some reason the text field accepts also characters witch was typed after first comma. I am not so familiar with `RegExp` so can anybody help me with ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex which allows the numbers which has 1 to 3 digits and these numbers must be separated by comma.

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/1)